# Book and Papers for properties of uniformly convex and locally uniformly convex and strictly convex Banach spaces.

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, convexity

I am looking for reference books and research articles which cover analysis of uniformly convex and locally uniformly convex  and strictly convex Banach spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you a nice book by B. Beauzamy titled "Introduction to Banach spaces and their geometry". See also this article

http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1955-078-01/S0002-9947-1955-0066558-7/S0002-9947-1955-0066558-7.pdf

You can extract useful information about requested topics.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The classical reference is:
M. M. Day, *Normed linear spaces*. Springer-Verlag, 1958
(reprinted: Academic Press, 1962)